# Travis-Ci after_deploy script is not working, and displaying success

Tags: amazon-ec2, travis-ci, aws-code-deploy

This my `.travis.yml` file. I am trying to automate deployment to `aws-codedeploy`.

```
language: node_js
node_js:
- 7.10.0
services:
- mongodb
env:
- PORT=6655 IP="localhost" NODE_ENV="test"
script:
- npm start &
- sleep 25
- npm test
deploy:
  provider: codedeploy
  access_key_id:
    secure: $Access_Key_Id
  secret_access_key:
    secure: $Access_Key_Secret
  revision_type: github
  application: Blog
  deployment_group: Ayush-Bahuguna
  region: us-east-2
after_deploy:
- "./build.sh"
```

Here `build.sh` is a shell script that generates the build files

```
cd /var/www/cms
sudo yarn install
npm run build-prod
```

And here is `.gitignore` file

```
node_modules/
client/dashboard/dist/
client/blog/dist/
```

The issue is that, even though travis-ci build succeeds, and `after_deploy` runs successfully, no build files are generated on the aws ec2 instance where my project is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see any deployment created on your AWS CodeDeploy console? And are your able to see the deployment status? If there is a deployment created, but failed, you can try to see the reason why it failed. Even though the deployment succeeded, it doesn't equal to all instances are deployed depends on the deployment configuration: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployment-configurations.html.

Thanks,
Binbin